# In OpenCL vector addition program, Memory Object and CL_INVALID_PLATFORM error

Tags: vector, parallel-processing, opencl

In the following OpenCL vector addition program, combining clCreateBuffer and clEnqueueWriteBuffer into single command,

gives the following error: cannot convert ‘_cl_mem*’ to ‘_cl_mem**’ in assignment/argument.

I get the same error in all the places where clCreateBuffer and clReleaseMemObject are used. Can anyone help me solve this error? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <wb.h> //@@ wb include opencl.h for you
#include <math.h>
//@@ OpenCL Kernel
const char* vaddsrc ="__kernel void vadd(__global const float *a,__global const float *b,__global float *result){int id = get_global_id(0);result[id] = a[id] + b[id];}";

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{

    unsigned int VECTOR_SIZE = 1024;
    int size = VECTOR_SIZE* sizeof(float);
    wbArg_t args;
    int inputLength;
    float *hostInput1;
    float *hostInput2;
    float *hostOutput;
    cl_mem *deviceInput1;
    cl_mem *deviceInput2;
    cl_mem *deviceOutput;

  args = wbArg_read(argc, argv);
  wbTime_start(Generic, "Importing data and creating memory on host");
  hostInput1 = (float *)wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 0), &inputLength);
  hostInput2 = (float *)wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 1), &inputLength);
  hostOutput = (float *)malloc(inputLength * sizeof(float));
   wbTime_stop(Generic, "Importing data and creating memory on host");
  wbLog(TRACE, "The input length is ", inputLength);


  //@@ OpenCL Context Setup Code (simple)
        size_t parmsz;
        cl_int clerr;
        cl_context clctx;
        cl_command_queue clcmdq;
        cl_program clpgm;
        cl_kernel clkern;

   clerr = CL_SUCCESS;
   clctx = clCreateContextFromType(0,CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, NULL, NULL, &clerr);
   clerr = clGetContextInfo(clctx, CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES, 0,NULL, & parmsz);
   cl_device_id* cldevs = (cl_device_id *) malloc( parmsz);
   clerr = clGetContextInfo(clctx, CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES, parmsz,cldevs, NULL);
   clcmdq = clCreateCommandQueue(clctx,cldevs[0], 0, &clerr);
   clpgm = clCreateProgramWithSource(clctx, 1, &vaddsrc,NULL, &clerr);
   char clcompileflags[4096];
   sprintf(clcompileflags, "-cl-mad-enable");
   clerr = clBuildProgram(clpgm, 0, NULL, clcompileflags,NULL, NULL);
   clkern = clCreateKernel(clpgm, "vadd", &clerr); 
  //@@ OpenCL Context Setup Code (simple)


  wbTime_start(GPU, "Allocating GPU memory.Copying input memory to the GPU.");
  //@@ Allocate GPU memory here Copy memory to the GPU here
  deviceInput1 = clCreateBuffer(clctx, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY |CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,             inputLength *sizeof(float), hostInput1, NULL);
  deviceInput2 = clCreateBuffer(clctx, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY |CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, inputLength *sizeof(float), hostInput2, NULL);
  deviceOutput = clCreateBuffer(clctx, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,inputLength *sizeof(float), NULL, NULL);  
  wbTime_stop(GPU, "Allocating GPU memory.Copying input memory to the GPU.");



  //@@ Initialize the grid and block dimensions here
size_t globalSize, localSize;
localSize = 64;
globalSize = ceil(inputLength/(float)localSize)*localSize;




  wbTime_start(Compute, "Performing CUDA computation");
  //@@ Launch the GPU Kernel here
clerr= clSetKernelArg(clkern, 0, sizeof(cl_mem),(void *)&deviceInput1);
clerr= clSetKernelArg(clkern, 1, sizeof(cl_mem),(void *)&deviceInput2);
clerr= clSetKernelArg(clkern, 2, sizeof(cl_mem),(void *)&deviceOutput);
clerr= clSetKernelArg(clkern, 3, sizeof(int), &inputLength);
 wbTime_stop(Compute, "Performing CUDA computation");


wbTime_start(Copy, "Copying output memory to the CPU");
//@@ Copy the GPU memory back to the CPU here
cl_event event=NULL;
clerr= clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(clcmdq, clkern, 1, NULL, &globalSize, &localSize, 0, NULL, &event);
clerr= clWaitForEvents(1, &event);
clEnqueueReadBuffer(clcmdq, deviceOutput, CL_TRUE, 0,inputLength*sizeof(float), hostOutput, 0, NULL, NULL);
wbTime_stop(Copy, "Copying output memory to the CPU");


wbTime_start(GPU, "Freeing GPU Memory");
//@@ Free the GPU memory here
clReleaseMemObject(deviceInput1);
clReleaseMemObject(deviceInput2);
clReleaseMemObject(deviceOutput);
wbTime_stop(GPU, "Freeing GPU Memory");
wbSolution(args, hostOutput, inputLength);
free(hostInput1);
free(hostInput2);
free(hostOutput);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use cl_mem as datatype for device buffers not cl_mem*
as cl_mem type is a handle to a "Memory Object", it shouldn't be a pointer

remove * in following lines

```
 cl_mem *deviceInput1;
 cl_mem *deviceInput2;
 cl_mem *deviceOutput;
```

**EDIT:**
You should not use 0 in first argument of clCreateContextFromType, as you'll get  CL_INVALID_PLATFORM error mentioned in this post

[How to remove CL_INVALID_PLATFORM error in opencl code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140989/how-to-remove-cl-invalid-platform-error-in-opencl-code)

I've given fixed code below:

```
#include <wb.h> //@@ wb include opencl.h for you
#include <math.h>
//@@ OpenCL Kernel
const char* vaddsrc ="__kernel void vadd(__global const float *a,__global const float *b,__global float *result){int id = get_global_id(0);result[id] = a[id] + b[id];}";

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{

    unsigned int VECTOR_SIZE = 1024;
    int size = VECTOR_SIZE* sizeof(float);
    wbArg_t args;
    int inputLength = VECTOR_SIZE;
    float *hostInput1;
    float *hostInput2;
    float *hostOutput;
    cl_mem deviceInput1;
    cl_mem deviceInput2;
    cl_mem deviceOutput;

  args = wbArg_read(argc, argv);
  wbTime_start(Generic, "Importing data and creating memory on host");
  hostInput1 = (float *)wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 0), &inputLength);
  hostInput2 = (float *)wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 1), &inputLength);
  hostOutput = (float *)malloc(inputLength * sizeof(float));
   wbTime_stop(Generic, "Importing data and creating memory on host");
  wbLog(TRACE, "The input length is ", inputLength);


  //@@ OpenCL Context Setup Code (simple)
        size_t parmsz;
        cl_int clerr;
        cl_context clctx;
        cl_command_queue clcmdq;
        cl_program clpgm;
        cl_kernel clkern;

// query the number of platforms
   cl_uint numPlatforms;
   clerr = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);
   cl_platform_id platforms[numPlatforms];
   clerr = clGetPlatformIDs(numPlatforms, platforms, NULL);
   cl_context_properties properties[] = {CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (unsigned long)platforms[0], 0};
   clctx = clCreateContextFromType(properties,CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, NULL, NULL, &clerr);
    clerr = clGetContextInfo(clctx, CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES, 0,NULL, & parmsz);
   cl_device_id* cldevs = (cl_device_id *) malloc( parmsz);
   clerr = clGetContextInfo(clctx, CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES, parmsz,cldevs, NULL);
   clcmdq = clCreateCommandQueue(clctx,cldevs[0], 0, &clerr);
   clpgm = clCreateProgramWithSource(clctx, 1, &vaddsrc,NULL, &clerr);
   char clcompileflags[4096];
   sprintf(clcompileflags, "-cl-mad-enable");
   clerr = clBuildProgram(clpgm, 0, NULL, clcompileflags,NULL, NULL);
   clkern = clCreateKernel(clpgm, "vadd", &clerr); 
  //@@ OpenCL Context Setup Code (simple)


  wbTime_start(GPU, "Allocating GPU memory.Copying input memory to the GPU.");
  //@@ Allocate GPU memory here Copy memory to the GPU here
  deviceInput1 = clCreateBuffer(clctx, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY |CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,inputLength *sizeof(float), hostInput1, NULL);
  deviceInput2 = clCreateBuffer(clctx, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY |CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, inputLength *sizeof(float), hostInput2, NULL);
  deviceOutput = clCreateBuffer(clctx, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,inputLength *sizeof(float), NULL, NULL);  
  wbTime_stop(GPU, "Allocating GPU memory.Copying input memory to the GPU.");



  //@@ Initialize the grid and block dimensions here
size_t globalSize, localSize;
localSize = 64;
globalSize = ceil(inputLength/(float)localSize)*localSize;




  wbTime_start(Compute, "Performing CUDA computation");
  //@@ Launch the GPU Kernel here
clerr= clSetKernelArg(clkern, 0, sizeof(cl_mem),(void *)&deviceInput1);
clerr= clSetKernelArg(clkern, 1, sizeof(cl_mem),(void *)&deviceInput2);
clerr= clSetKernelArg(clkern, 2, sizeof(cl_mem),(void *)&deviceOutput);
clerr= clSetKernelArg(clkern, 3, sizeof(int), &inputLength);
 wbTime_stop(Compute, "Performing CUDA computation");


wbTime_start(Copy, "Copying output memory to the CPU");
//@@ Copy the GPU memory back to the CPU here
cl_event event=NULL;
clerr= clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(clcmdq, clkern, 1, NULL, &globalSize, &localSize, 0, NULL, &event);
clerr= clWaitForEvents(1, &event);
clerr= clEnqueueReadBuffer(clcmdq, deviceOutput, CL_TRUE, 0,inputLength*sizeof(float), hostOutput, 0, NULL, NULL);
wbTime_stop(Copy, "Copying output memory to the CPU");


wbTime_start(GPU, "Freeing GPU Memory");
//@@ Free the GPU memory here
clReleaseMemObject(deviceInput1);
clReleaseMemObject(deviceInput2);
clReleaseMemObject(deviceOutput);
wbTime_stop(GPU, "Freeing GPU Memory");
wbSolution(args, hostOutput, inputLength);
free(hostInput1);
free(hostInput2);
free(hostOutput);

  return 0;
}
```

one more thing you can't just ask questions like that without much appreciable efforts from you

Comment: Your solution solved the problem. I m having an additional problem. 
hostinput1 has 0.1 and hostinput2 has 3.5.
I get the following error
Solution is not correct.
The solution did not match the expected results at row 0. Expecting 3.6 but got 0.
Does the input variables get reallocated to 0 before passing to the kernel?

Comment: View the Edit part of answer.

Comment: I m a newbie in OpenCL. Now i understood the mistake. thanks.